# I must use Google Cast SDK via the Chromecast device?

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

Thank you for spending time on my question !
Wish all of you have a good day!
Question:
①Could anybody tell me if i wanna use the Google Cast SDK to do the cast,i must have a Chromecast device?
②Can i do the cast between two android devices such as Phone and Tablet with the Google Cast SDK in my App?
③What does the receiver device in the remote display part mean? A android device with the receiver app or a special device such ac Chromecast?

Answer (score 0):

> Could anybody tell me if i wanna use the Google Cast SDK to do the cast,i must have a Chromecast device?

You must have something that is set up to work with the Cast protocol. That includes Chromecast devices and at least some Android TV devices.

> Can i do the cast between two android devices such as Phone and Tablet with the Google Cast SDK in my App?

No, at least for any phones and tablets that I am aware of.

> What does the receiver device in the remote display part mean? A android device with the receiver app or a special device such ac Chromecast?

There is no "receiver app" (unless you are referring to a custom receiver as being an app). In the Cast SDK, the receiver is running on the Chromecast/Android TV device and is responsible for playing back your requested media.